# Select text in a Quick Look window?

Tags: mac, quicklook

Is there any possibility (default write, or something else) to copy text directly from a quick look window? It annoys me that I cannot select and copy text snippets directly from Quick Look.

Answer (score 3):

In Terminal, enter:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection -bool TRUE
```

You have to restart Finder before the option will be available.

Found this on: http://www.defaults-write.com

Comment: Please notice that the activation of the "Text-Selection-In-Quicklook"-Feature could lead to the bug described in this question: 
[QuickLook having problems displaying some images](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128825/quicklook-having-problems-displaying-some-images)

Comment: I did what you have in the answer, restarted the Finder, but it seems like this does not work for macOS Catalina...